# form->select('group_id') only shows id and not the group in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm building a application where admins can add multiple users to groups. In the Add action of the UserController i've:

```
$this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));
```

The output should be a selectbox with the different group currently existing in the groups table.

```
Groups table:
   'id' 'group' 'comments'

Model (user):
   public $belongsTo = array('Group');

UserController:
   $this->set('groups', $this->User->Group->find('list'));

View (Users/add)
   echo $this->Form->input('Group_id');
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what version of cake are you using?

Comment: 2.1 currently as it's a new build.

Comment: you seem to do it correctly. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Group` class add this line

```
var $displayField = 'group';
```

This will tell the Cake that, for this class, it should treat `group` as if it was the `name` field in a standard model and `find('list')` will produce the results you want.

Comment: ... and it will automatically display the 'group' field where a 'name' field would normally be displayed in lots of other contexts as well.

Comment: usefull thing to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct, I assume you have group_id field in users table. You may want to try couple of things.

1. Change the case, e.g. Group_id to group_id
2. Change the display of select box as follow

   echo $this->Form->input('group_id', $groups);

Answer (score 0):

the case of the chars is pretty important in programming.
not only for files but also for class names and in your case the field names.
otherwise your code will not work correctly:

```
echo $this->Form->input('group_id');
```

should fix things.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the find('list') is looking for id and name, so you have to specify the fields in you case because you are missing the name field
I hope that helps